# some glyphicons showing, some not? Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with the following:

```
<p>This one isn't appearing ->> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span></p>

<p>But this one is ->>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></p>
```

At this URL:
http://1080422389.n303457.test.prositehosting.co.uk/property-detail.php?jbID=4

Why would one show but not the other.  Man I'm so confused!  :(
NJ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is, it's not declared in your Bootstrap CSS file. You might want to grab the latest pull of the [glyphicon font](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/fonts) and CSS declarations from GitHub, at least this part (but I would do the whole thing as it's possible it had been remapped):

```
.glyphicon-bed:before {
  content: "\e219";
}
```

Your version (3.2) was before they added the bed (3.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 files were out of date! glyphicon-bed is a new icon not featured in previous versions of Bootstrap whereas glyphicon-home has existed through various previous versions, if not all.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. When publishing a site on a webserver with bootstrap and glyphicons. I could not see glyphicons on that published site. It was no problem on our development system. Cause was an activated Javascript blocker. After making an exception for the published site it all worked fine again. Just wanted to mention it, in case someone is as stupid as me and runs into this...